# How can I display a popup on parent window from an iframe which contains a react app

Tags: reactjs

I have a chatbot running on some port. I have integrated it inside an iframe in a website. Is there any way to display an popup or modal outside of that iframe when clicking some link inside that chatbot?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very cool concept in react called [React Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) which allow you to render your component on any specific element even outside of your Root App.js component.